# Wicket Clean URLS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wicket-1.5, wicket-6

How can I build clean URLS in wicket. It's a wicket 1.5.7 project, that is being ported to wicket 6. But since I have no experience with Wicket I don't know how to clean the URLS.

> **My URL looks like this**:
>
> `http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/wicket/bookmarkable/en.mycompany.myprojectname.presentation.LoginPage`

A bit long and too much information.

> **I want it to look like**:
>
> `http://localhost:8080/myprojectname/LoginPage`

Where do I change it? Is it on the server side, or in some web.xml, or other config file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [mount](http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/chapter9.html#chapter9_6) your pages:

```
mountPage("/LoginPage", en.mycompany.myprojectname.presentation.LoginPage.class);
```

Usually this is done in by overwriting the [init](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html#init%28%29)-method of the WebApplication class.

Comment: Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: @SoumitriPattnaik: There are two WicketStuff projects which might be of interest: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Annotation and https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/wicket-mount-parent